# Controller does not get called in initializers closure

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to put the doctrine entity manager into many different classes in my ZF2 project. Thus. I have setup the following **initializer** in my `Module.php`:

```php
'initializers' => array(
      function ($instance, $services) {
            if (is_object($instance)) { // just for debugging
                var_dump(get_class($instance));
            }
            if (!$instance instanceof EntityManagerAwareInterface) {
                return;
            }

            $entityManager = $services->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
            $instance->setEntityManager($entityManager);
        },
    ),
)
```

Yet, it never gets called on my `AuthController` even though I am visiting a site of that controller (and get a null pointer exception, because the entity-manager was not set). Of course, the controller does implement the required interface:

```php
class AuthController extends AbstractActionController implements EntityManagerAwareInterface
```

Is there anything else I have to configure so that my `AuthController` is checked against the initializer closure?

At the moment I have it under **invokables** in `module.config.php`.

```php
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Auth\Controller\Auth' => 'Auth\Controller\AuthController',
    ),
),
```

When I remove it from there, the application cannot find the class anymore.

My debugging output lists other classes which are checked against the initializers, many managers and services. A small excerpt:

```php
string(37) "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\ControllerManager"
string(33) "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\PluginManager"
string(29) "Zend\\View\\HelperPluginManager"
[...]
string(24) "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Connection"
string(26) "Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityManager"
string(41) "Zend\\Authentication\\AuthenticationService"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an initializer for the controller manager too, judging by your debug output, the one you posted appears to be for the service manager. You configure other managers the same way, the method to use for controller manager is `getControllerConfig`

```
 public function getControllerConfig()
 {
      return array(
          'initializers' => array(
              // controller initializers here...
          ),
      );
 }
```